# What is the proper way to send a response form dialogflow from nodejs webhook?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm new to dialogflow and I've been trying to send a response from a nodejs webhook to my DF bot when a record has been added to a firestore DB. I've been searching a lot and I couldn't find either examples or docs that could help me understand.

This is the cloud function that performs the above:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const promise_mysql = require('promise-mysql');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulFillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body>>>>>>>> ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;

  db.collection('reservations').add(parameters).then(() => {
    agent.add("Room reversed!")
  }).catch((e => {
    agent.add('Something went wrong!!!!!')
  }))
});

// Other stuff
```

The issue (I think) is this part:

```
db.collection('reservations').add(parameters).then(() => {
    agent.add("Room reversed!")
  }).catch((e => {
    agent.add('Something went wrong!!!!!')
  }))
```

It adds the record perfectly but I can't get the dialogflow response to be shown as none of the options: `agent.add("Room reversed!")`, `agent.add('Something went wrong!!!!!')`

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Method1:**

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulFillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body>>>>>>>> ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;

  db.collection('reservations').add(parameters).then(() => {
    agent.add("Room reversed!")
    // Other stuff
  }).catch((e => {
    agent.add('Something went wrong!!!!!')
    // Other stuff
  }))
});
```

**Method2:**

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulFillment = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body>>>>>>>> ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;
  try {
      await db.collection('reservations').add(parameters)
      agent.add("Room reversed!")

  } catch (error) {
      agent.add('Something went wrong!!!!!')
  }
  // Other stuff
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that doing an async method the response will be sent to DF?